# WAS thin client deploy

Tags: java, websphere, wsadmin

Currently, I use WAS for deploying the java builds on a remote server. I need to remove whole big WAS server since I dont host any application as it is just for deployment using wsadmin.

I just want to retain the WAS libraries which may require for deployment remove everything else.

Is it possible to deploy with WAS but using only needed libraries?
If yes, what could be the procedure to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One such solution is described in [Using the latest Jython with a WebSphere Application Server wsadmin thin client](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1207_vansickel/1207_vansickel.html).

Another one is [WDR](https://wdr.github.io/WDR/).